# I want to add a store logo in footer

Tags: magento2, blocks, footer, logo

I'm new with magento 
i created new block for displaying it as a footer on my store.
i want to display a store logo inside the footer
thanks.
I'm using Magento 2.2.5 with Luma theme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a cms block and call in footer or you can add logo in any existing block :

create a cms block with any name i.e **footer_site_logo**, upload logo image and call html using

```
  <img src="{{media url='wysiwyg/your_site_logo.png'}}" alt="" />
```

then call your block in your theme layout ( Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml ) footer section like :

```
<block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="footer-socialmedia-link" after="-">
 <arguments>
    <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">footer_site_logo</argument>
 </arguments>
</block>
```